# Update URL parameter with user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL which is passed as a function parameter like:

```
requestCrossDomain('https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?&num=197110&lat=23&submit=Submit&hgt=100&veg=17&sitelev=&email=skip@larc.nasa.gov&p=grid_id&p=T10M&p=DLYRANGE&step=2&lon=16', function(results){

$('#loadedContent').css("display","").html(results);});

function requestCrossDomain( site, callback ) {


    if ( !site ) {
    alert('No site was passed.');
    return false;
    }


var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';


    $.getJSON( yql, cbFunc );

    function cbFunc(data) {

    if ( data.results[0] ) {

    data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');


    if ( typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(data);
    }
    }

    else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }
}
```

I am in need of changing the parameters in the URL corresponding to `lat=23` and `lon=16` to a user input.

I have tried doing it with `string.replace` but I am new to JavaScript. I cant get it working, how do I do this?

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far, to build upon?

Comment: Need a lot more information about how you are trying to do this and more code context

Comment: I have updated the code I have  developed so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this. Here is a full example per your comment:

```js
$(function(){
   function requestCrossDomain(site, callback) {
    if (!site) {
     alert('No site was passed.');
     return false;
    }
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);
    function cbFunc(data) {
     if (data.results[0]) {
      data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
       window[callback](data);
     } else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }
   }
   $('#test').click(function(){
    var url = 'https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?&num=197110&lat=23&submit=Submit&hgt=100&veg=17&sitelev=&email=skip@larc.nasa.gov&p=grid_id&p=T10M&p=DLYRANGE&step=2&lon=16';
    var newLat='lat='+ encodeURIComponent($('#lat').val());
    var newLon='lon='+ encodeURIComponent($('#lon').val());
    url = url.replace(/lat=[\d.]+/,newLat).replace(/lon=[\d.]+/,newLon);
    requestCrossDomain(url, 'someFunction');
   });
});

function someFunction(results){
    console.log(results);
    $('#loadedContent').css("display","").html(results);   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="lat" value="45"><br>
<input type="text" id="lon" value="31"><br>
<button id="test">Make URL</button>    
<br><br>
<div id="loadedContent"></div>
```

Comment: I guess this would work.. But could you please explain me how do i use the same in the codes I have mentioned above? Sorry, but I am very new to javascript programming. Big help. thank u

Comment: Thank u.. dat was exactly what i wanted... :)

Answer (score 2):

try a simple regex like this http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/zzaerydw/:

```
var url= 'https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?&num=197110&lat=23&submit=Submit&hgt=100&veg=17&sitelev=&email=skip@larc.nasa.gov&p=grid_id&p=T10M&p=DLYRANGE&step=2&lon=16';
var lat = 2222;//test
var lon = 1111;//test
//[0-9.] -> for integer or decimal
var result = url.replace(/lat=[0-9.]*/,'lat='+lat).replace(/lon=[0-9.]*/,'lon='+lon);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a template URL with `__placeholder__` text, replace it as needed.

E.g.

```
function requestCrossDomain(params) {
    var template = "https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?lat=__lat__&lon=__lon__&num=197110&submit=Submit&hgt=100&veg=17&sitelev=&email=skip@larc.nasa.gov&p=grid_id&p=T10M&p=DLYRANGE&step=2";

    for (var k in params)
        template = template.replace("__" + k + "__", encodeURIComponent(params[k]));

    console.log(template)
}

requestCrossDomain( {lat: 123, lon: 456} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it sounds like you are trying to do basic substring manipulation, with minor modifications something like this should work:

```
let url = 'https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?&num=197110&lat=23&submit=Submit&hgt=100&veg=17&sitelev=&email=skip@larc.nasa.gov&p=grid_id&p=T10M&p=DLYRANGE&step=2&lon=16'

// assuming you have two input elements 'lat' and 'lon'
let lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
let lon = document.getElementById("lon").value;

url = url.replace(/\&lat=[0-9.]*/, '&lat='+lat); 
url = url.replace(/\&lon=[0-9.]*/, '&lon='+lat);
```

Comment: You need to account for periods :)